# In MS-Access, can you Save multiple forms into 1 PDF

Tags: forms, ms-access, pdf, vba

I am creating a database in MS-Access to manage product specifications. Some products have overlapping specifications and some are unique.

My initial approach to this problem was to create multiple forms. For Example: an extension cord specification needs copper, compound and plug information. This information is also needed for a power strip specification, as well as other information that is ONLY pertinent to power strips. Currently I have created multiple forms for the different products. Is it possible to save multiple forms into a pdf for the same part number?

I know I can create a long form that is split on different pages, this method could work if I could not save or print certain pages depending on the product too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have shown in the picture below a portion of the forms and how some information is relevant only to the product class.

I know I could create forms for a basis of every category of inventory, but then I would have to create a full specification form for over 10 products, I am trying to streamline and reduce the amount of front end work required to generate specs from our database

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess that what you built is a BOM (Bill of Material). Anyway the way to go for producing a PDF, is a Report.

Comment: Okay, so I now realize that forms are for UI and reports are just for displaying information from the database. I question remains though, if I remake these forms as a report or as multiple reports, is there a way I can use a category field to choose which report pages to save as pdf?

Comment: When you open a report from VBA or from a macro, you can pass a criteria as an argument in order to filter the data to be included in the report. Also you can have a subreport within a report. And by the way; if you already spent time on your forms, you can Save them As a report.